# ofstream creates a file but doesn't write

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

Here's the code, I try to look up solutions but the things I've tried haven't worked.  Also, the if statement at the bottom of the main that checks if the file is opened, fails and says it cannot open the file, but I don't know what to do with that error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
const int row = 6;
const int col = 8;
void cellTemp (double check[][col], double);
int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    string input;
    ofstream out;
    string output;
    double grid[row][col];
    double t1, t2, t3, t4, tol;

    cout << "Enter input file name: \n";
    cin >> input;
    cout << "Enter output file name: \n";
    cin >> output;

    in.open(input.c_str());
    out.open(output.c_str());

    in >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4 >> tol;


    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
        {
            grid[i][c] = 0;
        }
    }

    //  Initializes top and bottom rows to 0
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        grid[0][i] = t1;
        grid[7][i] = t3;
    }
    //  Initializes left and right columns to 0
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        grid[i][0] = t4;
        grid[i][7] = t2;
    }

    cellTemp(grid, tol);
    if(out.is_open())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
            {
                out << grid[i][c];
            }
            out << endl;
        }
        out.flush();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file. \n";
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
void cellTemp (double check[][col], double tolerance){

    double copy[row][col];
    double max = 0;
    double prev = 0;
    double prevMax;
    double prevTol = tolerance;

    tolerance = -1;
    while(prevMax > tolerance)
    {
        tolerance = prevTol;
        //  Copies the array before performing actions
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
            {
                copy[i][c] = check[i][c];
            }
        }

        //  Sets cell values
        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int c = 1; c < 7; c++)
            {
                check[i][c] = (check[i-1][c] + check[i+1][c] +
                        check[i][c-1] + check[i][c+1]) / 4;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int c = 1; c < 7; c++)
            {
                prev = check[i][c] - copy[i][c];
                if(prev > max)
                {
                    max = prev;
                }
            }
        }
        prevMax = max;
        max = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting out of bound: `grid[7][i] = t3;`.

Comment: Try hard coding the file name with path and test to see if you get the same issues.

Comment: Which is it, the file is opened/created as your title says, or not as your question says? Where are you trying to put the output file?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. @Shibili your solution worked,  I feel silly for overlooking the bounds.

Comment: @Retired Ninja sorry about the ambiguity.  The error message I used was "cannot open file".  The program, however, did create and open the file but was not saving, I'm guessing due to the array being out of bound  as mentioned by Shibili and Paul Hashmi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grid[7][i] = t3;
```

you dont have [7] rows mate think you want grid[5][i] = t3; ?

Comment: No problem dshin